Is it normal for RAM clock/timing/command rate to keep switching?
Bought RAM upgrade for my Dell laptop. Original configuration was 1x8gb with stable clock/timing.
Upgraded to 2x8gb (matching pack) and it constantly switches between 1T and 2T, clock speed, timing every second or two according to HWinfo64.
Is this normal?

How are you detecting this?

@Mokubai using HWinfo64

@Giacomo1968 cautious..

A system adjusting its functions is pretty normal these days as hardware is better able to tune itself for given use cases for optimal power use and heat generation. As there is not an actual problem here, you may simply do some research on the capabilities of the specific hardware of your computer, and this may be sufficient information to answer you.

Consider how an automobile works: if the work gets harder (going uphill), more petrol is used. You want the clock speed to adapt to its load.
